# SQL Server : select each group of rows into a sing row

Tags: sql-server-2008

It's hard to describe what I'd like to find out. Roughly, it's "to select each group of rows into a sing row".

Please refer to the linked image.

Thank you!!

[click here for an image: SQL Server, select each group of rows into a sing row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpP7m.jpg)

**dbo.SourceTable**

```
group   column1 column2
------------------------
A   A1  AA1
A   A2  AA2
A   A3  AA3
A   A4  AA4
A   A5  AA5
B   B1  BB1
B   B2  BB2
B   B3  BB3
B   B4  BB4
B   B5  BB5
C   C1  CC1
C   C2  CC2
C   C3  CC3
C   C4  CC4
C   C5  CC5
D   D1  DD1
D   D2  DD2
D   D3  DD3
D   D4  DD4
D   D5  DD5
```

Desired result:

```
group   result1 result2 result3 result4 result5 result6 result7 result8 result9 result10
A   A1  AA1 A2  AA2 A3  AA3 A4  AA4 A5  AA5
B   B1  BB1 B2  BB2 B3  BB3 B4  BB4 B5  BB5
C   C1  CC1 C2  CC2 C3  CC3 C4  CC4 C5  CC5
D   D1  DD1 D2  DD2 D3  DD3 D4  DD4 D5  DD5
```

Comment: So in other words you want to PIVOT rows =).

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to pivot over more than one column. But there is a trick:

You can concatenate your both columns and do the pivot on the concatenated value. And even better: You can let the concatenated value look like XML (**without casting it to real XML**) and do the pivot on this. This approach makes it easy to get your values **typesafe** back.

But I must admit: It is quite a lot of typing :-)

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(groupColumn VARCHAR(1),Column1 VARCHAR(2),Column2 VARCHAR(3));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('A','A1','AA1')
,('A','A2','AA2')
,('A','A3','AA3')
,('A','A4','AA4')
,('A','A5','AA5')
,('B','B1','BB1')
,('B','B2','BB2')
,('B','B3','BB3')
,('B','B4','BB4')
,('B','B5','BB5')
,('C','C1','CC1')
,('C','C2','CC2')
,('C','C3','CC3')
,('C','C4','CC4')
,('C','C5','CC5')
,('D','D1','DD1')
,('D','D2','DD2')
,('D','D3','DD3')
,('D','D4','DD4')
,('D','D5','DD5');

SELECT p.groupColumn
      ,casted.Xml1.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)') AS Result1a
      ,casted.Xml1.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)') AS Result1b
      ,casted.Xml2.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)') AS Result2a
      ,casted.Xml2.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)') AS Result2b
      ,casted.Xml3.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)') AS Result3a
      ,casted.Xml3.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)') AS Result3b
      ,casted.Xml4.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)') AS Result4a
      ,casted.Xml4.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)') AS Result4b
      ,casted.Xml5.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)') AS Result5a
      ,casted.Xml5.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)') AS Result5b
      ,casted.Xml6.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)') AS Result6a
      ,casted.Xml6.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)') AS Result6b
      ,casted.Xml7.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)') AS Result7a
      ,casted.Xml7.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)') AS Result7b
      ,casted.Xml8.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)') AS Result8a
      ,casted.Xml8.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)') AS Result8b
      ,casted.Xml9.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)') AS Result9a
      ,casted.Xml9.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)') AS Result9b
      ,casted.Xml10.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)') AS Result10a
      ,casted.Xml10.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)') AS Result10b
FROM
(
    SELECT groupColumn
          ,'result' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY groupColumn ORDER BY Column1,Column2) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS ColumnName 
          ,'<x>' + Column1 + '</x><x>' + Column2 + '</x>' AS PivotColumn
    FROM @tbl
) AS pvt
PIVOT
(
    MIN(PivotColumn) FOR ColumnName IN(result1,result2,result3,result4,result5,result6,result7,result8,result9,result10)
) AS p
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT CAST(p.result1 AS XML) AS Xml1
          ,CAST(p.result2 AS XML) AS Xml2
          ,CAST(p.result3 AS XML) AS Xml3
          ,CAST(p.result4 AS XML) AS Xml4
          ,CAST(p.result5 AS XML) AS Xml5
          ,CAST(p.result6 AS XML) AS Xml6
          ,CAST(p.result7 AS XML) AS Xml7
          ,CAST(p.result8 AS XML) AS Xml8
          ,CAST(p.result9 AS XML) AS Xml9
          ,CAST(p.result10 AS XML) AS Xml10
) AS casted
```

The result

```
groupColumn Result1a    Result1b    Result2a    Result2b    Result3a    Result3b    Result4a    Result4b    Result5a    Result5b    Result6a    Result6b    Result7a    Result7b    Result8a    Result8b    Result9a    Result9b    Result10a   Result10b
A   A1  AA1 A2  AA2 A3  AA3 A4  AA4 A5  AA5 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
B   B1  BB1 B2  BB2 B3  BB3 B4  BB4 B5  BB5 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
C   C1  CC1 C2  CC2 C3  CC3 C4  CC4 C5  CC5 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
D   D1  DD1 D2  DD2 D3  DD3 D4  DD4 D5  DD5 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Your hammer is certainly XQuery/XML =)

Comment: Yeah, whenever a tiny problem crosses my way I take the XXLXML and **SMASH!!!** But I must admit, that the aggregate-CASE-approach is very nice too, voted it.

Comment: It's not just nice, it will outperform yours. PIVOT usually performs worse than the old-school PIVOT method, plus all the XML parsing will certainly slow things down. Anyway, always good to know that XML-magic can do it too =)

Comment: @TT. Yes, you are surely right. So dear JoonYoung Kim: If you want to accept one of these answers, I'd advise you to take TT's answer. And I'll try to create a handle of pure *Aggregate-Case* to make my *XXLXML hammer* even mightier! :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tt(id INT IDENTITY(1,1),[group] VARCHAR(16),[column1] VARCHAR(16),[column2] VARCHAR(16))
INSERT INTO #tt([group],[column1],[column2])VALUES
    ('A','A1','AA1'),
    ('A','A2','AA2'),
    ('A','A3','AA3'),
    ('A','A4','AA4'),
    ('A','A5','AA5'),
    ('B','B1','BB1'),
    ('B','B2','BB2'),
    ('B','B3','BB3'),
    ('B','B4','BB4'),
    ('B','B5','BB5'),
    ('C','C1','CC1'),
    ('C','C2','CC2'),
    ('C','C3','CC3'),
    ('C','C4','CC4'),
    ('C','C5','CC5'),
    ('D','D1','DD1'),
    ('D','D2','DD2'),
    ('D','D3','DD3'),
    ('D','D4','DD4'),
    ('D','D5','DD5');

;WITH group_order AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        group_order_id=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [group] ORDER BY id)
    FROM
        #tt
)
SELECT
    [group],
    result1=MAX(CASE WHEN group_order_id=1 THEN [column1] END),
    result2=MAX(CASE WHEN group_order_id=1 THEN [column2] END),
    result3=MAX(CASE WHEN group_order_id=2 THEN [column1] END),
    result4=MAX(CASE WHEN group_order_id=2 THEN [column2] END),
    result5=MAX(CASE WHEN group_order_id=3 THEN [column1] END),
    result6=MAX(CASE WHEN group_order_id=3 THEN [column2] END),
    result7=MAX(CASE WHEN group_order_id=4 THEN [column1] END),
    result8=MAX(CASE WHEN group_order_id=4 THEN [column2] END),
    result9=MAX(CASE WHEN group_order_id=5 THEN [column1] END),
    result10=MAX(CASE WHEN group_order_id=5 THEN [column2] END)
FROM
    group_order
GROUP BY
    [group];

DROP TABLE #tt;
```

Results:

```
+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
| group | result1 | result2 | result3 | result4 | result5 | result6 | result7 | result8 | result9 | result10 |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
| A     | A1      | AA1     | A2      | AA2     | A3      | AA3     | A4      | AA4     | A5      | AA5      |
| B     | B1      | BB1     | B2      | BB2     | B3      | BB3     | B4      | BB4     | B5      | BB5      |
| C     | C1      | CC1     | C2      | CC2     | C3      | CC3     | C4      | CC4     | C5      | CC5      |
| D     | D1      | DD1     | D2      | DD2     | D3      | DD3     | D4      | DD4     | D5      | DD5      |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+
```